# why viewModel is not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have a MainActivity in which I am using a few Fragments using Navigation components, but my app is crashing lateinit var viewModel is not initialized error, i am not able to figure out why my viewmodel is not intilized

Error

```
  Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
    at com.choudhary.newsappmvvm.ui.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:18)
    at com.choudhary.newsappmvvm.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment.onViewCreated(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:27)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
```

My MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


 lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val repository = NewsRepository(ArticleDataBase(this))

    val viewModelFactory = NewsViewModelFactory(repository)

    viewModel   = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)


    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
}
```

My viewModelFactory Class

```
class NewsViewModelFactory(private  val repository: NewsRepository)  :
ViewModelProvider.Factory {

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return NewsViewModel(repository) as T
}
}
```

inside Fragment i using like this

```
class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {





lateinit var  viewModel : NewsViewModel
lateinit var  newsAdapter : NewsAdapter

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel  =(activity as MainActivity).viewModel

    setUpRecylerView()

    viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response->

        when(response){

            is Resource.Success ->{
                hideProgress()
                response.data?.let {  newsResponse ->
                     newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                }
            }

            is Resource.Error ->{

                hideProgress()
                response.messsage?.let {

                    Log.d("somnath", it)
                }
            }

            is Resource.Loading ->{
                showProgress()
            }
        }
    })

}
```

My dependepencies

```
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'



implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'

   // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

// Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"

// Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'



// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0"

// Navigation Components
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1"

// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

My NewsRepository

```
class NewsRepository(
val db : ArticleDataBase
) {

suspend fun getBreakingNews(countryCode : String,pageNum : Int) =

    RetrofitInstance.api.getBreakingNews(countryCode, pageNumber = pageNum)

}
```

My Database class for room

```
@Database(
entities = [Article::class],
version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
 abstract class ArticleDataBase  : RoomDatabase() {

abstract  fun getArticlesDao(): ArticleDao

companion object{
    @Volatile
    private  var INSTANCE : ArticleDataBase ? = null
    private  val LOCK = Any()

    operator  fun invoke(context : Context)  = INSTANCE ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
        INSTANCE ?: createDatabase(context).also{ INSTANCE = it}
    }

    private  fun createDatabase(context: Context ) =

        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            ArticleDataBase::class.java,
            "article_db.db"
        ).build()
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the `BreakingNewsFragment` initialized?

Comment: i dont know i m using nav graph for fragments

Comment: Use shared viewmodel

Comment: It sounds like you are using the `<fragment>` tag in your activity XML? Don't you get a warning to replace that with `FragmentContainerView`? Please confirm.

Comment: yes i m using fragment now replce with FragmentContanerView , now getting new error  cannot find implementation for com.choudhary.newsappmvvm.ui.db.ArticleDataBase. ArticleDataBase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're relying on your `Activity`'s `onCreate` running before your `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated` does, and that's not always the case. That's why this:

`viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel`

is accessing your `lateinit` `viewModel` property before it's been initialised.

---

You shouldn't really have `Fragment`s accessing `ViewModel`s through the `Activity` itself, because of issues like this. They have separate lifecycles, and it can be tricky to juggle them and ensure things like this. That's part of why the  `ViewModel` library was created, so you don't need to worry about it because the complexity is handled for you!

So your `Fragment` should also be using `ViewModelProvider` to grab the VM. Since you want the same copy the `Activity` holds, just pass the `Activity` to the constructor, so it fetches the VM associated with that

```
// in the Fragment

lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val repository = NewsRepository(ArticleDataBase(requireContext()))
    val viewModelFactory = NewsViewModelFactory(repository)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
```

This is using `requireActivity()` and `requireContext()` because [you have access to those by the time `onCreate` runs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created). The `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`, which has been *instantiated*, but isn't necessarily in the `CREATED` state yet, which is the whole problem here. So you can pass the `Activity` to the `ViewModelProvider` to fetch its instance of the VM, creating one for it if necessary

---

Also if this `Fragment` is the only thing using this `NewsViewModel`, and it's not shared, then the `Activity` doesn't need to be involved at all. So all this code could be in the `Fragment` instead of duplicated in both (and passing the `Fragment` to `ViewModelProvider` instead)